# Recent posts and first featured

Tags: posts

I have the code below to list the recent posts on my site. It's working fine.

I need to style differently the first post (bigger image and bigger title).

Any idea how ?

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="main-content span12">
        <div class="main-content span4">
            <!--Image article-->
            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'medium' ); ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="main-content span8">
            <!--Titre article-->
            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
            <!--Extrait article-->
            <?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be using CSS, so you don't have to change the PHP. Assuming you have a  or some other wrapping element that contains all your posts, you could use something like

```
.main-content.span12 img {
    width:50%;
    height:auto;
}
.main-content.span12 h4 {
    font-size:1em;
}
.main-content.span12:first-child img {
    width:100%;
}
.main-content.span12:first-child h4 {
    font-size:2em;
}
```

`:first-child` will get only the first child of the parent element - so it will apply to only the first `<div class="main-content span12">`.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite difficult to answer without knowing exactly what you are looking for, but let's take a look at what you can do.

**Option 1**

You can create a file named `content-featured.php` in your template's directory, and put your custom structure inside it. Then, call the template file in your loop:

```
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            /*
             * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
             */
            get_template_part( 'content','featured' );
        endwhile;
        endif;
```

This way, you don't have to touch anything but the newly created template file.

**Option 2**

Change the structure of your provided code. I assume you are using some sort of bootstrap-like styling sine you've got the `span4` and `span12` classes. Here is what you can do:

The class `main-content span12` is where your content is being wrapped. This is at max width, since they width is set to `span12` (judging by the names). It will have a width of 100%.

Moving to the next element, the `DIV` with the class `main-content span4`. Here is where your image is rendered. You can increase the size of it by using `span5` or `span6` instead. But remember to change the next DIV's width respectively so they match for a total of 12. So if you use `span5`, you should use `span7` for your next `DIV`.

If you want a bigger image, you can use a larger thumbnail size:

`<img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'large' ); ?>">`

Now move onto the next element and decrease the width of it by using `span7` instead of `span8`. Your content is stored here.

`the_excerpt()` returns a short part of your content. If you want to show the full content, use `the_content()` instead.

Changing the `<h4>` to a lower or higher value can also decrease/increase the size of your header.

After all, if it's not enough, you can append a custom class to your DIV and then style if afterward:

```
div class="main-content span12 my-class">
        <div class="main-content span4 my-class-image">
            <!--Image article-->
        </div>
        <div class="main-content span8 my-class-content">
            <!--Titre article-->
            <h4>...</h4>
            <!--Extrait article-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

This way the classes are unique for your featured article. Using a CSS then can help you style it:

```
.main-content.my-class{
    //Your desired style
}
.main-content.my-class-image {
    //Your desired image size
}
.main-content.my-class-image img {
    //You can even set the image's size specifically here 
}
```

I hope this helps you get a better understanding of styling WordPress's posts.